# Failed to compile. typeerror: cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: compilation, typeerror, undefined

Everything is fine. Site run locally no issue. But when type **npm run build** it says, failed to compile.

`typeerror: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tolowercase') at array.some (<anonymous>) at runmicrotasks (<anonymous>)`
[Vs code Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5Ytj.jpg)

Funny thing is i never use tolowercase function in this project. But shows error.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the comments you have in your css files. worked for me